# How to customize google sign in button?

Tags: ios, google-signin, gidsignin

1) When I created a `UIView` which has size (x, y), and made its type `GIDSignInButton`, it shows up a Google Sign In button in the size (z, t) where `z < x` and `t < y`. Why? How can I make it show a Google Sign In button with size (x, y)?

2) I added Google Sign In SDK with CocoaPods. How can I set the alignment of the text in the Google Sign In button? How can I set the font size?

I added Google Sign In button as described in the Google's doc.

Answer (score 5):

**Customize GIDSignInButton**

**For your both questions:**

Google doesn't allow us to customise the `GIDSignInButton` in every way. But There are some properties available that we can change.

The properties are mentioned below and explained how to set them. We will set these properties on the outlet button named `signInButton`.

1. `GIDSignInButtonStyle` : The layout style for the sign-in button.

   ```
   [self.signInButton setStyle:kGIDSignInButtonStyleIconOnly];
   ```

   The `style` property has three possible values.

   - `kGIDSignInButtonStyleStandard` : : 230 x 48 (default)
   - `kGIDSignInButtonStyleWide` : 312 x 48
   - `kGIDSignInButtonStyleIconOnly` : 48 x 48 (no text, fixed size)
2. `GIDSignInButtonColorScheme` : The color scheme for the sign-in button.

   ```
   [self.signInButton setColorScheme:kGIDSignInButtonColorSchemeDark];
   ```

   The `colourScheme` property has two possible values.

   - `kGIDSignInButtonColorSchemeDark`
   - `kGIDSignInButtonStyleWide` : (Default)
3. `IBOutlet UIViewController *` : Delegate

   ```
   DelegateViewController *uiVC = [[DelegateViewController alloc] init];
   [self.signInButton setDelegate:uiVC];
   ```

If you want google sign in button as just logo, you will have to set the view size bigger then 48X48, which is default size for the logo.

For further references you can visit [Google Sign-In for iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/)