# Custom Google Sign-In button - iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios9, google-signin

I want to customize Google Sign-In button like below:-
[image]

I have tried below links, but none of them helped really much:-
[How to customize google sign in button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586960/how-to-customize-google-sign-in-button)
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/

Could somebody please guide what I should do? I can't use Google+ Sign-In button because "[Google+ Sign-In is deprecated](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/)".

Edited:- I tried the code provided on below link:-
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in#add_the_sign-in_button

Comment: have you tried any code than paste in here

Comment: @Birendra I have edited my question. There was not much code provided by Google. You can check the link. I think you haven't read my question completely.

Comment: hi you have a skype id then give me so i can send a code

Comment: you have use this code

Comment: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    GPPSignIn *SignIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    
    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"532796865439-juut4g2toqdfc13mgqu5v9g5cliguvmg.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    
    SignIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];
    return YES;
}

Comment: -(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if ([GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]) {
        
        return YES;
    }
    
    return wasHandled;
}

Comment: In your Appdelegate.m file

Comment: hi if not done than I update my answer so please check it and if any issue then tell me

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can add your own button instead of using Google Sign-In button
Do follwing things

## Objective C Version

1)Add your own button into storyBoard

2)drag action into viewController

```
- (IBAction)googlePlusButtonTouchUpInside:(id)sender {
     [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
     [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate = self;
     [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
  }
```

3)handle delegate methods

**#pragma mark - Google SignIn Delegate**

```
- (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error {

  }
```

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

//completed sign In

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
//user signed in
//get user data in "user" (GIDGoogleUser object)
}
```

## Swift 4 Version

In Swift make sure you have added briding header as the library is written in objective C

1)Add your own button into storyBoard

2)drag action into viewController

```
@IBAction func googlePlusButtonTouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate=self
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate=self
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
```

3)handle delegate methods

**//MARK:Google SignIn Delegate**

```
func signInWillDispatch(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {
}
```

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google

```
func signIn(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    presentViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
  self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view

```
func signIn(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
    dismissViewController viewController: UIViewController!) {
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

//completed sign In

```
   public func signIn(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInForUser user: GIDGoogleUser!,
      withError error: Error!) {
        if (error == nil) {
          // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
          let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
          let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
          let fullName = user.profile.name
          let givenName = user.profile.givenName
          let familyName = user.profile.familyName
          let email = user.profile.email
          // ...
        } else {
          print("\(error.localized)")
        }
    }
```

Edit: Here is the reference/evidence for usage of custom button, [Google Doc reference](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in)

> In these examples, the view controller is a subclass of
>   UIViewController. If, in your project, the class that implements
>   GIDSignInUIDelegate is not a subclass of UIViewController, implement
>   the signInWillDispatch:error:, signIn:presentViewController:, and
>   signIn:dismissViewController: methods of the GIDSignInUIDelegate
>   protocol. Also don't forget to set UI delegate      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.uiDelegate = self

Comment: Ok. Let me try this. Thanks.

Comment: @Rohit KP. I am getting crash at [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn] in button method.

Comment: Does apple will rejecte the app due to own button instead of using Google Sign-In button ?

Comment: @TrongVu: No, There is no reason for rejecting App. I already have app live on App store with the custom button. I have edited the answer & added reference from google document. Please refer it. Thanks for pointing.

Comment: i am trying to use custom image , it is not working with custom image. above code is not working.if i use the above code , button clicked does nothing.

Comment: Calling signOut before calling signIn will bring up the prompt window again

Comment: First three methods are not needed if your class is subclass of UIViewController. From Google -> "// Implement these methods only if the GIDSignInUIDelegate is not a subclass of
// UIViewController."

Comment: First Set the delegate, and UIDelegate then call GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()  Enjoy

Comment: @RohitSisodia thanks, I have updated the answer. It was mistyped while translating to swift from objective C.

Comment: Why not mention the actual delegate that must be added to the VC declaration?

Comment: nice work @RohitKP for swift 4.0 we have updated your answer in swift 4.1

Comment: `uiDelegate` is no more working. Please refer to the following link for updates: [link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide#objective-c)

Answer (score 8):

Swift 3 Version

In Swift make sure you have added briding header as the library is written in objective C.

1. Add your own button into storyBoard
2. drag action into viewController

   ```
   @IBAction func googlePlusButtonTouchUpInside(sender: AnyObject) {
         GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
   }
   ```
3. handle delegate methods

   ```
   //MARK:Google SignIn Delegate
    func signInWillDispatch(signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: NSError!) {
     // myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
       }

   // Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
      func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                 present viewController: UIViewController!) {
           self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
       }

   // Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
                 dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }

   //completed sign In    
   public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

           if (error == nil) {
         // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
               let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
              let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
               let fullName = user.profile.name
              let givenName = user.profile.givenName
              let familyName = user.profile.familyName
              let email = user.profile.email
             // ...
           } else {
               print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
           }
       }
   ```

Answer (score 7):

For Swift 4: (This is working code Enjoy)

```
@IBAction func logimByGoogle(_ sender: Any) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}
//MARK:- Google Delegate
func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {

}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
          present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!,
                   withError error: Error!) {
    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        // ...
    } else {
        print("\(error)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

All are fine with the answer of [@Rohit KP (https://stackoverflow.com/a/34368678/2905967)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34368678/2905967)

But Little adding when assigning the delegates.

Please call your action like this:

```
- (IBAction)btnGooglePlusPressed:(id)sender
{
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate=self;
    [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].uiDelegate=self;
    [[GIDSignIn sharedInstance] signIn];
}
```

and add these delegates `GIDSignInDelegate,GIDSignInUIDelegate`

Answer (score 3):

In GoogleSignIn SDK 5.0 and above GIDSignInUIDelegate has been revoked

Add this below line, for custom google login button

```
@IBAction func googleLoginPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Man! Finally, it helped me. Very minor change but can be missed easily.

Answer (score 2):

Swift-5 Copy paste and Enjoy

```
@IBAction func btngoogle(_ sender: UIButton) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
}


//MARK:Google SignIn Delegate
func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {
    // myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
}
// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
          present viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!,
          dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//completed sign In
public func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if (error == nil) {
        // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
        let userId = user.userID                  // For client-side use only!
        let idToken = user.authentication.idToken // Safe to send to the server
        let fullName = user.profile.name
        let givenName = user.profile.givenName
        let familyName = user.profile.familyName
        let email = user.profile.email
        // ...
    } else {
        print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own button instead of using Google Sign-In button Do follwing things

1)Add this code in AppDelegate.m file

2)Add your own button into storyBoard and give class name as GPPSignInButton and set UIImageView on that button.

3)drag action into viewController

AppDelegate.m file

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    GPPSignIn *SignIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];

    [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].clientID = @"532796865439-juut4g2toqdfc13mgqu5v9g5cliguvmg.apps.googleusercontent.com";

    SignIn.scopes = @[kGTLAuthScopePlusLogin];
    return YES;
} 

-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    if ([GPPURLHandler handleURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation]) {

        return YES;
    }

    return wasHandled;
}




ViewController.m file

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet GPPSignInButton *btn;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

   [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
    [[GPPSignIn sharedInstance] trySilentAuthentication];

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
  }



-(void) finishedWithAuth:(GTMOAuth2Authentication *)auth error:(NSError *)error
{
    GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
    signIn.shouldFetchGoogleUserEmail = YES;
    signIn.delegate = self;

    if (error == nil) {
        if(auth.canAuthorize){
            GTLServicePlus *service = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init];
            [service setRetryEnabled:YES];
            [service setAuthorizer:auth];

            GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"];


            // 1. Create a |GTLServicePlus| instance to send a request to Google+.
            GTLServicePlus* plusService = [[GTLServicePlus alloc] init] ;
            plusService.retryEnabled = YES;

            // 2. Set a valid |GTMOAuth2Authentication| object as the authorizer.
            [plusService setAuthorizer:[GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication];

            // 3. Use the "v1" version of the Google+ API.*
            plusService.apiVersion = @"v1";
            [plusService executeQuery:query
                    completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,
                                        GTLPlusPerson *person,
                                        NSError *error) {
                        if (error) {
                            //Handle Error
                        } else {
                            NSLog(@"\nEmail= %@", [GPPSignIn sharedInstance].authentication.userEmail);
                            NSLog(@"\nGoogleID=%@", person.identifier);
                            NSLog(@"\nUser Name=%@", [person.name.givenName stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", person.name.familyName]);
                            NSLog(@"\nGender=%@", person.gender);
                        }
                    }];

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: GTLServicePlus service is stopping support (https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/people). We have to use the Google Sign In

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4.2

to make a custom Google button :

1-add your button to storyboard

2-create @IBaction for your button

3-follow instructions on https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in
but replace this step

"2 .In the view controller, override the viewDidLoad method to set the UI delegate of the GIDSignIn object, and (optionally) to sign in silently when possible"

with

-> insert this code in the button action

```
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate=self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
```

now you can happily customize your button,hope this answer help you.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5.2:-**

```
Add below lines in your view controller

func googleLoginButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for swift, its very simple and works like a champ.

1. Create reference for your Google Sign In button

   @IBOutlet weak var signInButton: GIDSignInButton!
2. set style for it in viewDidLoad

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   //Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     signInButton.style = GIDSignInButtonStyle.iconOnly
   ```

3.Place your custom button above the google sign in button in main story board and        create an action reference for it. Inside it click the google sign in button programmatically.

```
    @IBAction func googleSignIn(_ sender: Any) {
    signInButton.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
    }
```