# change dismissVC to presentVC

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using following method two times for login and sign up. So some times I am getting crash. Here is my code:

```
- (void)signIn:(NSDictionary *)params {
    [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] showActivityControllerWithMessage:nil inController:self];

    [[PCWebServiceManager sharedWebServiceManager] signInWithParameters:params completionHandler:^(id responseObject, NSError *error) {
        self.signInBtn.enabled = YES;
//        [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] hideActivityIndicator];

        if (error) {
            [self forceLogout];

            [PCUtilities showAlertWithTitle:nil message:error.localizedDescription cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"];
            [[PCUtilities sharedUtilities] hideActivityIndicator];

        }else {
            PCLoginObject *loginObject = (PCLoginObject *)responseObject;
            [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
                [self performSelector:@selector(handleSignInResponse:) withObject:loginObject afterDelay:0.2];
            }];
        }
    }];

}
```

In above code I am using this method as two time in two different classes, so if possible can any one help me to change the below line from `dismissviewcontroller` to `presentViewcontroller`

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO
                         completion:^{
                             [self performSelector:@selector(handleSignInResponse:)
                                        withObject:loginObject
                                        afterDelay:0.2];
                         }];
```

---

I am using above method two times. So according to crash report I need to change any one method to `present view controller`. I have tried but no success.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'When |allowsSignInWithWebView| is enabled, uiDelegate must either be a |UIViewController| or implement the |signIn:presentViewController:| and |signIn:dismissViewController:| methods from |GIDSignInUIDelegate|.'  this is that ereo

Comment: Why isn't that information in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this method ,this helped me in my case,when I got this warning

//pragma mark - Google SignIn Delegate

```
- (void)signInWillDispatch:(GIDSignIn *)signIn error:(NSError *)error {

}
```

// Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

// Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn dismissViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

//completed sign In

```
- (void)signIn:(GIDSignIn *)signIn didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
     withError:(NSError *)error {
//user signed in
//get user data in "user" (GIDGoogleUser object)
}
```

Comment: actually your last code //completed sign delegate i am having already. And in my above code i posted one of that method will call after the `google plus` delegate. inside that method also i am having some method will call..So in order to call the another method how will i use the present and dismiss view controller

Comment: see my dismiss VC code inside that i am calling`handlesigninresponse` so how to add that method in your presentVC code?/

Comment: The above code is for Google signIn,,Have you used custom button or used the button given by SDK

Comment: i used custom button.. if so i will upload the full code how i use that google plus for both sign in and sign up

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368613/custom-google-sign-in-button-ios/34368678#34368678 please refer my answer it will help you

Comment: and use google sign In instead of G+ ..Because G+ is deprecated they suggest to use google signIn

Answer (score 0):

Try to set

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
```

in your viewDidAppear method,not in viewDidLoad

Comment: i have two classes `login.m`  and `signup.m`   in both class i have to add this above code??

Comment: @metronic: why it should be added to viewDidAppear