# Custom Button for google and Facebook Sign-In Swift2 ios

Tags: swift, facebook, authentication, google-plus, custom-controls

I want to create custom buttons for Facebook and Google Sign-In in my Application. I have done this with Facebook. Now I am trying to create Sign-In with Google using custom button. I have following issues.

**1.** I want to know that as shown in screenshot I am getting this alert. I don't want that Alert. How can I remove that.. I didn't code for that. Is it default?

**2.** How can I use custom button with Google Sign-In. I have added "GoogleSignIn.bundle" and "GoogleSignIn.framework". I am not able to do this with custom button. I have successfully done this with in-built button. Please help me to solve this.

[image: screenshot]

I have referred this link for login with Facebook. [Facebook integration with swift](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/facebook-integration-using-swift)

Comment: try this fo google sign in button
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift#add_the_sign-in_button

Comment: I tried this. but this uses **GIDSignInButton**. which is in-built. I want to use custom button

Comment: make a Action for your custom button and call       GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn() .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368613/custom-google-sign-in-button-ios

Comment: Yah. Thanks.. I just tried it.. It worked!!.

Comment: Can you tell me about this dialog of Facebook Log In.?? Is it default??

Comment: i guess it's native Apple functionality.