# Google SignIn - Always return "The user canceled the sign-in flow"

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, google-signin

I am using below code snippet for signin with google, but always returning **"The user canceled the sign-in flow"**

```
if GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.hasPreviousSignIn() {
            
    logout()
}else {
    guard let clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID else { return }
    let signInConfig = GIDConfiguration.init(clientID: clientID)
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(with: signInConfig, presenting: getWindowTopController()) { user, error in
                
    guard error == nil else { return }
                
    guard let authentication = user?.authentication,let idToken = authentication.idToken else { return }
 }
```

> Error : Error Domain=com.google.GIDSignIn Code=-5 "The user canceled
> the sign-in flow." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The user canceled
> the sign-in flow.}

Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: make sure you have valid data in `GoogleService-Info.plist`, and you have followed all other [steps](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/start-integrating), like URL scheme

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I added valid data and followed all the steps.

Comment: @bathi how did you solved this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

The GIDSignInButton object don't need addTarget in code or linking @IBAction. The GIDSignInButton class already handle that action for us.

Got it from here
[How to fix `The user canceled the sign-in flow.` with Sign In with Google on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54806794/how-to-fix-the-user-canceled-the-sign-in-flow-with-sign-in-with-google-on-ios)

If above code not works, try the below one

[Custom Google Sign-In button - iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34368613/custom-google-sign-in-button-ios)