# is it possible to change the look of the Google SignIn Button?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, google-cloud-functions, google-signin

The title pretty much says it.

No matter how I try to add modifiers or try change it the Google Sign In button won't let me change it's look which is strange because the look in the screenshot of my view isn't at all what I see other apps using - most other apps have Red or Blue button with the Google G or a lower cased g.

Has anyone run into this and have a good solution? Thanks in advance!

To note, I'm building in SwiftUI and my backend is Firebase Auth, though I don't think this matters.

[at the least how can i match the hieght?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb6y0.jpg)

I've tried everything in this post many do not work, but regardless I dont really want to have to create and maintain a custom button for this.. [Custom Button for google and Facebook Sign-In Swift2 ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540504/custom-button-for-google-and-facebook-sign-in-swift2-ios)

at the very least why can I change the hieght or add a frame? Here is the code I have for the button in my View.  The implementation is working as expected - I just want to change things cosmetically. The frame line doesnt have any effect

````
 //Adds Sign In with GOOGLE Button (async func)
            GoogleSignInButton(viewModel: GoogleSignInButtonViewModel(scheme: .dark, style: .wide, state: .normal)) {
                
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await viewModel.signInGoogle()
                        showSignInView = false //if success dismiss the screen
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 55)```
````

Comment: The Google sign in button is written in UIKit. You aren't going to affect it with SwiftUI modifiers.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this as a community wiki for visibility. According to @Yrb

> The Google sign in button is written in UIKit. SwiftUI modifiers will not affect it.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33586960/how-to-customize-google-sign-in-button) elaborates how you can modify the Google sign-in button. For further reference, you can visit [Google Sign-In for iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in#using-uikit).